# java memory usage from method call

Tags: java, memory-management

I'm trying to solve a problem on codeeval but am running into a problem with using too much memory. In my code there is a loop that runs many many times (~10,000^2) due to a large input that is unavoidable. I noticed that if I run the loop and do nothing on each iteration I use about 6MB of memory in total with my other code. However, if I add a simple method call in the loop that just calls a function that returns false, my memory usage jumps to 20MB.

Why is this? Shouldn't the memory allocated for each function call get deallocated after the function call is finished?

EDIT:
The full code is quite large and irrelevant to post but this snippet is what I described. If I do not include the `foo()` call, my code as a whole runs using 6MB of memory. If I include the `foo()` call, my code as a whole runs using 20MB of memory. The `foo()` method in my actual code does literally the same thing (return false) because I wanted to test out the memory usage.

This is for a coding challenge on codeeval so the problem should be solvable in any language they allow so java should be fine.

EDIT: I've refactored some of my code so that I could pull out an entire function to show you guys. This still produces the same result described before. The function call that produces the weird behavior is `are_friends()`.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> graph(String[] word_list) {

    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> adj_list = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();

    for (int i = 0; i < word_list.length; i++) {
        adj_list.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < word_list.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < word_list.length; j++) {
            if (are_friends(word_list[i], word_list[j])) {
                adj_list.get(i).add(j);
                adj_list.get(j).add(i);
            }
        }
    }

    return adj_list;
}

boolean are_friends(String a, String b) {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Post your relevant code please, which preferably should be compilable.

Comment: The memory is deallocated when the GC decides when to deallocate it. The only guarantee you have is that it will try to deallocate memory before throwing an OutOfMemoryError. Show your code. (But if 20MB is too much, you should probably not use Java)

Comment: You can try to reuse your variables. Try declaring your boolean outside of your loop and then just setting it's value inside.

Comment: @skiwi yea, sorry. Fixed it

Comment: Does the memory consumption scale linearly with the size of your input?  How much does it use with 1000?  2000?  4000?

Comment: @user1529956 I find it very unlikely that calling `foo` repeatedly would have any memory impact. Can you try to show a complete, runnable example that reproduces the issue?

Comment: @TedBigham I'm not sure how to test it locally. I'm reading the output from submitting an answer to codeeval and it lets me know how much memory my code used

Comment: @assylias I am pretty sure it gives inpact, refer to my answer to why I think it will do so.

Comment: @skiwi Yes I've seen that - I don't really buy it.

Comment: @assylias That's exactly what I thought too, which is why I'm confused. I can't really post a runnable example because I don't even have the input for my function because it's not disclosed on codeeval.

Comment: When objects are created inside a loop the garbage collection might not kick in, as long there is room on the heap. However if one would subtract the garbage collectable object, there is sufficient free space. This is in fact a speed optimization.

Comment: Resubmit your code using (word_list.length / 2) and see if it uses half as much memory.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any control over the input at all. Something else weird just happened as well. I submitted my code with the foo() and it used 6.4MB but when I submitted immediately after again it used 20MB. Now I'm thinking it has something to do with codeeval. Thanks everyone. Will still be trying to figure it out

Comment: Actually change your code you have (word_list.length / 2) instead of word_list.length in both spots, and post the memory usage it reports.

Comment: @TedBigham oh right, sorry. I wasn't thinking clearly in the AMs. For reasons regarding the other code, I can only test it out on the inner for loop. Using `word_list` used 20mb while `word_list/2` used 6mb. Very weird

Comment: see my edit for some more code

Answer (score 1):

> If I include the foo() call, my code as a whole runs using 20MB of memory.

You should be careful about definitive claims on the memory usage of a Java program.

- do you mean *retained memory*?
- do you mean "I saw it in Task Manager/top/other process-monitoring tool"?
- do you mean "I profiled it with VisualVM or similar, and that was the peak heap usage"?

With each of these approaches you'll probably be getting wildly different measurements.

One relevant indicator of memory usage would be setting the maximum heap size with `-Xmx` to, say, 16 MB, and seeing whether your program is able to complete error-free in one or the other of its forms. Note that this will limit only the heap and not the stack or any other support memory areas used by the JVM.

Without limiting the heap as above the JVM is free to use as much of it as it sees fit, keeping a lot of garbage around to avoid GC stalls.

Comment: When I run my code on codeeval it just lets me know that it's used ~20mb. I say ~20mb because it gives me the exact bytes and after multiple trials I noticed it averages around 20mb.

Comment: That datum is useless as a basis for any kind of explanation. Either find an authoritative specification of what exactly their number measures, or repeat the measurement on your own setup.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are experiencing is that now it will first call a method, namely `foo()`, as many times as the loop runs.
And methods end up on the call stack and need extra time to be processed, for more in depth explanation you will need to google I'm afraid.

The point is that when you put the `return false` inside `bar()`, it **does not** manage the call stack, hence using less memory and possibly being faster.

I believe that at some point, if running on a Hotspot JVM (the default one), the JVM will *inline* your `foo()` method call, hence resulting in the behaviour as if you had a `return false` directly in `bar()`. When it optimizes, and if it does at all, depends on the JVM arguments and your specific version/system.

*However* even if it has optimized, the memory will already be claimed by the JVM. Even though the memory is **not in use** anymore by the JVM, it will refuse to give it back to your *Operating System*, thus you still observe the higher memory usage.

Comment: Compare the memory usage of `public static void main(String[] args) { while(true) { if (foo()) break; } }` vs `public static void main(String[] args) { while(true) { if (false) break; } }`. No difference at all on my machine... One obvious reason being that `foo` will get inlined pretty quickly, making the two codes exactly the same at the assembly level. Even without inlining, the call stack in only one level deep at all time and I don't see how that is going to use any significant amount of memory.

Comment: @assylias how do you see the memory usesage locally? Perhaps I can debug it better if I could do that as opposed to submitting to codeeval to see as I've been doing

Comment: @user1529956 visual vm

Answer (score 0):

> Shouldn't the memory allocated for each function call get deallocated after the function call is finished?

No.  The memory used for calling a function goes on the stack. That stack is allocated when the thread starts and doesn't get freed until the thread exits.

> Why is this?

I believe you have not presented all the relevant information for the problem.  I just tried to reproduce the problem on CodeEval and got the same memory usage with and without the nested loop (within 500K).

It's worth noting that identical code produces a different memory result on CodeEval from run to run.  I haven't seen anything deviations as wild as what you've seen, but there's clearly more factors involved than just the code.